# Load xml document into a variable - jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to load xmldocument content into a variable but without success.

The returned data is undefined.  What is the problem here?

When I use firebug, I see that the response is populated fine with all the xml code.

Can somebody help me?

```js
    function loadXmlForm() 
    {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        alert('Start');
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET" ,
            url: template_path + 'axFormDefinition.xml',
            dataType: "xml",                
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);                
            }
        });
    }
```

Update: -> The ajax call generates an error, it not enters in the success block, where the responseText returns me the xml code....any ideas why?

```
function loadXmlForm() 
    {
        var xml;

        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET" ,
            url: template_path + 'axFormDefinition.xml',
            dataType: "xml",                
            success: function(data){
                xml = data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                returnxhr.responseText; 
            } 
        });
        return xml;
    }
```

Here the request details (you can see that I get successfully the xml code in the response, but the ajax call returns error). Is it because the response header is empty?

[Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxoCD.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcmMu.png)

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` print?

Comment: unfortunately in the ide i can not use console.log, just alert.....alert gives me undefined, the ajax call respones gives me the xml code....